Streamlit Fragment/Partial rerun
I have a Streamlit dashboard where I pull data from Google Sheets and create some basic figures. At the end, I want to include a summary feature so that the user can generate a desired summary based on a multi-select and dataset. My goal is to rerun only a specific portion of the code (the part that generates the summary) rather than the entire code. To achieve this, I used the fragment feature of Streamlit. However, the issue is that it does not update the input value (in this case, df, which is the initial dataset when the app starts and does not change based on the selected project). I want to use the fragment feature, but df should update based on the previous part of the code.
@st.fragment
def fragment_function():
    disag=st.multiselect('Create Summary (Disaggregation by):', df.columns.tolist(),help='This option is used to create summaries based on selected columns.!')#,default=['Date'])
    if disag:
        if len(disag) == 1:
            disag_t=df.groupby(disag).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'N'})
            disag_t.loc[len(disag_t)] = ['Total', disag_t['N'].sum()]
        else:
            disag_t = df.groupby(disag).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
            disag_t.loc['Total'] = disag_t.sum()
    
        
        st.dataframe(disag_t)

fragment_function()

I tried Fragment feature, it works but the input dataset does not get updated. Alway generates the same summary for different projects (project is selected the first of streamlit app and dataset is pulled accordingly but fragment just gets the first load of dataset and doesnot update it if project is changed)
